# How To delete Queue in ActiveMQ in linux

Tags: linux, activemq-classic

I am working on a Monitoring application in which i have to delete all JMS queues if it reaches the threshold of 2000. so can anyone help me to write a command in linux?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shell script as it offers commands to manage a ActiveMQ broker. Take a look at: http://activemq.apache.org/unix-shell-script.html

Comment: thanku and how i can perform the same operation with rabbitMQ?

Comment: Ask a new question in the RabbitMQ tag